# Xcode skipping Starting Number in Build Identifier

Tags: xcode, ios6

I am developing a ios app with name 101brainexercises. The product name in Project Build settings is 101BrainExercises. But the BuildIdentifier name is as com.neurotrain.-01BrainExercises.

If i give the product name as BrainExercises101  then it works fine i.e., com.neurotrain.BrainExercises101.

Am using Xcode 4.5.2 and IOS6 SDK
Any help would be appreciated

--
Thanks.

Comment: Use the name that works then.

Comment: I have to stick to the numericstarting name. Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project name is restricted by [RFC 1035](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) (DOMAIN NAMES - IMPLEMENTATION AND SPECIFICATION), specifically:

```
<domain> ::= <subdomain> | " "
<subdomain> ::= <label> | <subdomain> "." <label>
<label> ::= <letter> [ [ <ldh-str> ] <let-dig> ]
<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
<let-dig-hyp> ::= <let-dig> | "-"
<let-dig> ::= <letter> | <digit>
<letter> ::= any one of the 52 alphabetic characters A through Z in
upper case and a through z in lower case
<digit> ::= any one of the ten digits 0 through 9
```

In other words the "label" part must start with a letter.